# How to create list of binary values based on values in one column DataFrame on one row in python?

Tags: python

So I want to create a binary label from multilabel. My code which does not work looks like this:

```
bin_lbl=[0 if label in ['zero', 'No Label'] else 1 for label in lbl]
```

so it should return 0 for position where lbl is "zero" or "No label" and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Please add the error or wrong result you are getting. And what datatype is `lbl`?

Comment: it returns only number 1 (because it satisfy "else" ?? ) and lbl is pandas.DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after 2 hours of suffering:

```
bin_lbl=[0 if lbl.iloc[x].item() in ['zero', 'No Label'] else 1 for x in range(len(lbl))]
```

... I got a warning that `.item()` will be removed in future versions, so if anyone has better idea please share.